# PHP - MYSQL Connection Isuue

Tags: php, mysql

I am Using XXAMP, and  I am trying to add a new user to the database. But after completing the form in Register.php, the user is not added to the database (phpmyadmin). I don't have any error messages produced, so its very hard to troubleshoot.

The objective will be to add the new user into the phpmyadmin database in localhost:8080. Thank you.

**Register.php**

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addadminprofile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addadminprofile" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addadminprofile">Add Admin Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action="code.php" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-body">


       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      </div>

  </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="registerbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
  </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","adminpanel");

if(isset($_POST['registerbtn']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

    if($password === $cpassword)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO register (username,email,password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(query_run)
        {
            //echo "Saved";
            $_SESSION['success'] = "Admin Profile Added";
            header('Location: register.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Admin Profile NOT Added";
            header('Location: register.php');
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Password and Confirm Password Does Not Match";
        header('Location: register.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your quotes are wrong in the insert query..you're insert '$email' literally now

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based admin gui written in PHP for managing MySQL databases. Your application talks to MySQL directly and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I'm a beginner with PHP

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: `if (query_run)` should be `if ($query_run)`. You're missing `$` in front of the variable name.

Comment: @Oil - There's nothing wrong with the quotes in the query. Since the query is inside double quotes, the variable values will be inserted. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Enable error-reporting and see what it tells you. The typo that @Magnus Eriksson pointed out should be giving a warning. But it also shouldn't stop the query running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please try it... You will get an error if unsuccessful. So, know the reason

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addadminprofile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addadminprofile" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addadminprofile">Add Admin Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action="Code.php" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['err']; ?>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      </div>

  </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="registerbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
  </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Code.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","adminpanel") or die($connection->connect_errno);

$_SESSION['err']=$connection->error;

if(isset($_POST['registerbtn']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

    if($password === $cpassword)
    {   
        $query = "INSERT INTO `register`(`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$email."','".$password."')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if($connection->error){
            $_SESSION['err'] = $connection->error;
        }
        else $_SESSION['err'] = "Congratulations! You are Successfully Added";
        if($query_run)
        {
            //echo "Saved";
            $_SESSION['success'] = "Admin Profile Added";
            header('Location: register.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Admin Profile NOT Added";
            header('Location: register.php');
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Password and Confirm Password Does Not Match";
        header('Location: register.php');
    }
}

?>
```

> Be sure about Database structure

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, It did throw up an error here in the modal, but I am unsure as to how to troubleshoot from this:

Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/register.php on line 213

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/register.php on line 213

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/register.php on line 213

Comment: plz replace that line by   <?php if(isset($_SESSION['err'])){echo $_SESSION['err'];}; ?>

Comment: or you can remove it (line: 213)

Comment: Fixed- Thanks for your help. Actually the issue was with the DB, your annotated picture helped.